# Which folder does Windows 10 store the wi-fi drivers?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, windows-10, drivers, wifi-driver

Yesterday my Wi-Fi Adapter suddenly disappeared from the taskbar icon. I was unable to connect my laptop even after several restarts and various attempts. I then opened Settings to find that the "Wi-Fi" option is missing there too. The "Broadcom BCM43142 802.11b/g/n Wireless Adapter" entry is missing from the Device Manager but the "Broadcom Bluetooth 4.0 Adapter" entry is present.

I figured out, maybe the driver must be at fault, so I downloaded a latest one from HP's website for my model (Pavilion 15 p027tx), the HP Support Assistant fired up and notified that the driver has been installed successfully. I opened the Uninstall Program menu, but it still showed the old driver 6.223.215.5 and not the new one I downloaded, 7.35.275.2 Rev.B. So I uninstalled the old one and restarted the PC again, but still it did not help. Can anybody please help me locate the drivers folder? Thanks.

Comment: If the device is gone from Device Manger, it is likely NOT a driver issue. You probably want the try toggling the physical Wi-Fi switch (could be certain function key combination) or look for related BIOS/UEFI option.

Comment: Update: You were right, it was not a driver issue, otherwise it shows in Device Manager. In fact, it was a hardware issue. Had complete motherboard replaced under warranty, now it is working fine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows stores all drivers here:
c:\windows\system32\DriverStore\FileRepository

You are better off checking the **Uninstall driver** from the **Device Manager** than trying to remove them this way.

The folder above is highly protected by windows.

Comment: Thanks, cybernard. Took a long time to realise my motherboard was at fault. It has since been replaced, thanks to HP's usually good ( but time consuming ) ADP support.

Comment: P.S.: Yes you are right, better to manage drivers for all components from the Device Manager rather than fiddling directly with the C:\ drive.